# Reading data from HBase in Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

Am new to Hadoop and HBase. Let me explain my question with an example. The data is made small for brevity.

Lets assume we have a file named item.log and it contains following information.

> ```
> ITEM-1,PRODUCT-1
> ITEM-2,PRODUCT-1
> ITEM-3,PRODUCT-2
> ITEM-4,PRODUCT-2
> ITEM-5,PRODUCT-3
> ITEM-6,PRODUCT-1
> ITEM-7,PRODUCT-1
> ITEM-8,PRODUCT-2
> ITEM-9,PRODUCT-1
> ```

I have a map reduce code as below,

```
package org.sanjus.hadoop;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class ProductMapReduce {

    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            String[] columns = value.toString().split(",");
            
            if (columns.length != 2) {
                System.out.println("Bad line/value " + value);
                return;
            }
                       
            Text word = new Text(columns[1]);
            LongWritable counter = new LongWritable(1L);
            
            output.collect(word, counter);
        }
    }
    
    
    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<LongWritable> iterator, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            long sum = 0L;
            
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                sum += iterator.next().get();
            }
            output.collect(key, new LongWritable(sum));
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(ProductMapReduce.class);
        conf.setJobName("Product Analyzer");
        
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        
        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        
        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
        
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

**LABEL 1:** Output after map reduce is below:

> ```
> PRODUCT-1   5   
> PRODUCT-2   3
> PRODUCT-3   1
> ```

Here is a question:

I have a table in HBase, which has the following information stated below.

> ```
> PRODUCT-1   10$
> PRODUCT-2   20$
> PRODUCT-3   30$
> ```

**Question/Requirement:** I want the output of the reduce phase as a consolidation of the reduce output in the "LABEL 1: " and the HBase table stated above

> ```
> PRODUCT-1   10$ * 5 = 50$
> PRODUCT-2   20$ * 3 = 60$
> PRODUCT-3   30$ * 1 = 30$
> ```
>
> Basically, Key is PRODUCT-1, Value in HBase Table for this key is 10$ and the value of the same key from reducer is 5 and both values are multiplied. ($ symbol is for understanding)

Note: Examples I found in are based on the input or output to HBase. My scenario is, input and output will be a file in HDFS, while I need to process the reducer outputs with information in HBase Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since HBase supports high read throughput and you want to just read data in the reducer (a controlled number of them will be used):
You can use HBase API to read the data from the table based on key of the reducer. Since reads in Hbase are fast (~10ms depending on size of data fetched) i do not think your performance will be impacted. 
Just make sure you initialize the Configuration & HTable in the configure() method of reducer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did,

inside my reducer class, I added the overloaded method 'setup'

```
private HTable htable;

private Configuration config;

protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.addResource(new Path("/etc/hbase/conf.hbase1/hbase-site.xml"));
    try {
        htable = new HTable(config, "MY_TABLE");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error getting table from HBase", e);
    }

}
```

Using the HTable.get api, I got the Result object.

Comment: In your reducer did you extend the TableReducer class?

Comment: @shash, I extended 'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer' class in my reduce implementation.